# Do all X-Wings have retractable short-range anti-personnel cannons?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology

Poe flew an X-Wing - not his own signature fighter, probably a stock-issue to hide his identity - early in the movie that featured a retractable anti-personnel turret gun, much like the one on the Millenium Falcon, that is able to engage in a firefight with attacking stormtroopers, with enough power and accuracy to take them out with one shot.

I don't think I've ever seen this before. Is this within regulation or a special modification, and is it a design feature that has always been there or only in the newer post-Endor models of the X-Wing?

Comment: the Visual Dictionary mentions that the Resistance X-Wing has "modular secondary weapon pods", which can mount proton torpedoes, laser cannons, or "different ordnance": http://i.imgur.com/UFqrltO.jpg Unfortunately, it doesn't indicate WHERE these pods are mounted, so I'm not sure if that accounts for the turret underneath the fuselage.

Comment: the Cross-Sections book does indicate where the proton torpedoes are mounted on Poe's X-Wing, but the clearest images I can find still have the actual label swallowed up in between the pages: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4HQF8ZR8_zU/VnSGmssOuJI/AAAAAAAACeo/ajKbr8GBddc/s1600/DSC_0392-2.jpg

Comment: So, hopefully someone who actually owns the books can help with this. If the proton torpedo rack on Poe's X-Wing is in the same place as the cannon on the first X-Wing he uses, that would seem to indicate that they're the same modular bay.

Comment: @recognizer - I've got the book. There's nothing hiding in the fold that sheds any extra light. It just says *"Proton Torpedo Firing Rack"*

Comment: @Richard I don't suppose there's another page with details of a blue-and-white X-Wing, indicating any differences from Poe's custom hot rod, is there?

Comment: @recognizer - Alas no.

Answer (score 4):

It's apparently a standard feature on the X-wings used by the Resistance. [*The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) mentions the turret gun in its profile on standard T-70 X-wings:

> **Data File**
>
> Manufacturer: Incom-FreiTek
>
> Model: T-70 X-wing
>
> Affiliation: Resistance
>
> Height: 2.71m (8ft 11in) (landing gear extended)
>
> Length: 12.48m (41ft)
>
> Crew: 1 pilot, 1 astromech
>
> Weapons: 4 Taim & Bak KX12 laser cannons, 2 Krupx MG7 proton torpedo launchers (8 torpedoes, standard configuration), **underslung antipersonnel blaster cannon**
>
> (page 81, emphasis added)

There's no mention in any source I've found of this cannon being present on X-wings predating the T-70. For example, [*Rebel Starfighters: Owners' Workshop Manual*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Starfighters_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual) also lists "Underslung blaster cannon (concealed)" on its profile of the T-70, but not on its profile of the T-65Bs seen in the Original Trilogy.